# How do I change the separator in parameterize for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This seems like a dumb question, but how do I use `parameterize` in Rails? I've seen this doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize

In my Model I can get `string.parameterize` to work, but I don't understand how to use the `separator` param. `parameterize(string, separator: '')` says I can't use parameterize on main, and `string.parameterize(separator: '')` says can't implicitly convert from Hash to String

Comment: Pretty sure you use it like in the docs `parameterize("Donald E. Knuth", separator: '_')`. What's your string? What rails version?

Comment: Rails 4.2.6; When I type that line into rails console I get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method `parameterize' for main:Object`

Comment: I think you need to `include ActiveSupport::Inflector` in your console before using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`string.parameterize` without specifying any character will give you your string separated by words, removing any character that's not a letter, and "joining" them with `'-'`:

```
string = 'Donald E. Knuth'
string.parameterize
# => "donald-e-knuth"
```

This way specifying a separator:

```
string.parameterize(separator: '*')
# => donald*e*knuth
```

The method acts using the `I18n.transliterate` method to the passed string, and then applying a destructive `gsub!` which will check any non-letter character and apply the substitution, is like to do:

```
# without separator specified
I18n.transliterate(string).gsub!(/[^a-z0-9\-_]+/i, 'separator')
# => Donald-E-Knuth
```

So this way if there's no separator specified, the method has one already defined as its third parameter:

```
def parameterize(string, sep = :unused, separator: '-', preserve_case: false)
  ...
end
```

<s>Note the use is first the `string` and then the `parameterize` method call, unlike what the documentation exemplifies.</s>

Note: Tested on ruby `2.3.1` and Rails `5.0.2` it works well, Rails `4.2.5`, `4.2.6` (as you say) and `4.2.7` throws this error:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.5)
> string  = 'x y z'
# => "x y z" 
> string.parameterize(separator: '*')
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
```

In Rails < 5 it must be used as `ActiveSupport::Inflector.parameterize(string, separator)`:

```
> @item = Item.first
# => #<Item id: 1, name: "new item" ...> 
> ActiveSupport::Inflector.parameterize(@item.name, '*')
# => "new*item"
```

Comment: `string.parameterize(separator: '*')` is not working for me. `string = 'xyz'`. I am getting the error `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String` in Rails Console

Comment: Could you add the whole code to try reproduce your problem?

Comment: `rails c`; `string = 'xyz'`; `string.parameterize(separator: '*')`;

Comment: It seems a problem of version, in ruby 2.3.1 and Rails 5.0.2 it works correctly, [check](https://gifyu.com/image/SXYy)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/parameterize) for more info:

```
parameterize("Donald E. Knuth", separator: '_') # => "donald_e_knuth"
parameterize("^trÃ¨s|Jolie__ ", separator: '_') # => "tres_jolie"
```

This method comes from the [ActiveSupport::Inflector](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector) class, so you can do:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.parameterize("Hello World Yeah!", separator: "*")
# => "Hello*World*Yeah!"
```